# Spring Cloud Contract - Stub Runner for messaging by using AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSpec

Tags: spring-integration-dsl, spring-cloud-contract, spring-integration-amqp

I tried to integrate Spring Cloud Contract Verifier Stub Runner’s messaging module with Spring AMQP. I created `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with `MessageListener` and it works fine. 
But I have another approach. I use a AMQP support for Spring Integration with Inbound Channel Adapter to receive a message from a queue.
Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Contract Verifier Stub Runner’s messaging module for AmqpInboundChannelAdapter?

**CONTRACT**

```
Contract.make {
    description 'insert new message'
    label 'test.queue.insert'
    input {
        triggeredBy('insertMessage()')
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo 'test.exchange'
        headers {
            header('contentType': 'application/json')
            header('__TypeId__': 'sk.bulalak.messaging.demospringcloudcontractmessaging.Person')
        }
        body('''{"firstName": "Janko", "lastName": "Hrasko"}''')
    }
}
```

**APPLICATION**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class DemoSpringCloudContractMessagingApplication {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringCloudContractMessagingApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue testQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("test.queue").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Exchange testExchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder
                .topicExchange("test.exchange")
                .durable(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding testBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(testQueue())
                .to(testExchange())
                .with("#")
                .noargs();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, testQueue()).messageConverter(messageConverter))
                .handle(p -> logger.info(p.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "org.example:test-service")
public class DemoSpringCloudContractMessagingApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private StubTrigger stubTrigger;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        boolean result = stubTrigger.trigger("test.queue.insert");

        assertTrue(result);
    }

}
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener

    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.SpringAmqpStubMessages.send(SpringAmqpStubMessages.java:100)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.SpringAmqpStubMessages.send(SpringAmqpStubMessages.java:89)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.sendMessage(StubRunnerExecutor.java:235)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.triggerForDsls(StubRunnerExecutor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.trigger(StubRunnerExecutor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunner.trigger(StubRunner.java:146)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner.trigger(BatchStubRunner.java:131)
    at sk.bulalak.messaging.demospringcloudcontractmessaging.DemoSpringCloudContractMessagingApplicationTests.contextLoads(DemoSpringCloudContractMessagingApplicationTests.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the AMQP stub runner support `stubrunner.amqp.enabled=false` and just use the Spring INtegration one.

Custom route:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">


    <!-- REQUIRED FOR TESTING -->
    <bridge input-channel="output"
            output-channel="outputTest"/>

    <channel id="outputTest">
        <queue/>
    </channel>

</beans:beans>
```

and run the test with that context

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config, loader = SpringBootContextLoader)
@ImportResource("classpath*:integration-context.xml")
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
class IntegrationStubRunnerSpec extends Specification {
```